# Stretch cockpit image across three monitors in Flight Simulator

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I want to stretch my Flight Simulator cockpit image across three monitors. All the answers I have seen so far relate to wallpaper stretching across three monitors.

Fusion will only allow me to stretch across two monitors. If I try to stretch across the third one, the image turns black. I have two monitors set up with an NVIDIA video card and the third monitor is set up using a USB adaptor to a DVI connection.

Comment: I realise that there's two interpretations to this - are you trying to game with two monitors, or view an image across multi monitors? What is fusion? Do you mean [displayfusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/)?

Comment: Indeed, I got a bit confused now as well. What programs are you using or are you talking about wallpapers? Are you using a program to visualize images?

Answer (score 2):

I use [Ultramon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) and it might be capable of doing what you are trying to do. I have an image spread across 2 monitors and it's great. It brings many more features that you can check on the homepage.

It's not that expensive but might be a barrier of course, however I totally recommend it for Windows 7 and before. Take a look at the wallpaper options of the program:

[image: Ultramon wallpaper management]

Obviously operating systems continue to grow and will, eventually, bring all these features by default. (i.e: Windows 8 now brings a taskbar for each monitor, Windows 7 didn't)

Answer (score 1):

The third monitor (the one that goes black) is probably the one on the USB/DVI port.

Firstly, with there's almost no way to stretch a image between display devices (though SLI/Crossfire would let you do that by making two or more cards as one) - though [softth](http://www.kegetys.fi/SoftTH/) may *possibly* work in this scenario - they advice using a PCIe card as a secondary adaptor, but claim it may work with PCIe or AGP.

Which brings us to a bigger issue - USB video adaptors often hardly have the bandwidth to do full motion video, let alone games - even if you get softth to work, you may not get acceptable performance off it.